# Edit NSPredicate using NSPredicateEditor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nspredicate, nspredicateeditor

I have a NSPredicateEditor from which I want to extract the predicate as a string. I'm using the following code:

```
[[predicateEditor objectValue] description]
```

and it extract the predicate in a form like this:

```
"Author" MATCHES "John"
```

the problem is that in this predicate I can't find any hint about the first part of the NSPredicateEditor, the ANY/ALL part.

[image]

How can I extract it in NSString form? Thanks

Comment: I got it, I have to check for AND/OR in the string when adding more than one row in the predicateeditor

Comment: You shouldn't use `description` to get the String value of the predicate. Use something like `yourPredicate.predicateFormat` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that for a single case the predicate intrinsically/logically contains "ALL" behavior, without the `"ALL"` string  actually needing to be set in the predicate.

Logically `"author matches john"` is the same as `"ALL(author matches john")`.

If you create an `NSCompoundPredicate` and set it as the `NSPredicateEditor`'s `objectValue` the "All" row should be displayed automatically, even if the predicate format string itself does not contain the string "ALL". But setting a standard `NSPredicate` (rather than `NSCompoundPredicate`) may not give you the ALL row.